# Undefined Reference to ' '

Tags: linux, rpc, undefined-reference

I have an rpcgen generated file 'api_svc1.c' The file contains the following line:

```
local = (char *(*)(char *, struct svc_req *)) createacct_5_svc;
```

'createacct_5_sv' is declared in 'api.h' as

```
createAcctResult * createacct_5_svc();
```

But even after includeing the header file 'api.h', I get the following error:

```
api_svc1.c:90: undefined reference to `createacct_5_svc'
```

Aby suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if you have "api.h", then you also have "api.c", in which case you have to *link* your api.c file to ap_svc1.c. Note that the error is not a compiler error complaining about a missing header; it's a **linker** error complaining about a not found (irresolvable) symbol after compiling to object code at the linking phase.

Comment: Hi H2CO3, we don't have an api.c here. rpcgen utility generates api server stub file, api client stub file and an api header (api.h).

Comment: You have to have a .c file in which you have the function. You can maybe use the `grep` utiliy to search for its name in .c files, then use your compiler to link it.

Comment: then where is the implementation of that function? api.h contains only the prototype, the implementation must be in a .c file somewhere, typically api.c. if you don't have it, then you won't be able to link to that function.

Comment: The function definition is present in api client stub file generated by rpcgen. This is a C file.

Comment: Then link to that file along with the file you have the error in, and that should be fine.

Comment: Hi H2CO3, If I link the api client stub file which contains the function definition, I get the error  "multiple definition of `createacct_5' "

Comment: You're doing something *really* wrong. If you get a "Multiple definition" error now, you should not have got an "Undefined reference" error before, without linking it...

Comment: Maybe you're accidentally `#include`ing a .c file as well?